# Powershell: Create restore points hourly

Tags: powershell

Our users need to have "previous version" of files that must be saved hourly druing the working hour per day.

There is a work around for this by using vbs then schedule it to run hourly, it will create "restore point" each hour.

```
strDesc = "Automatic Restore Point"
Set oRestorePoint = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:SystemRestore")
strResult = oRestorePoint.CreateRestorePoint(strDesc, 0, 100)
```

I want to make this happen by using powershell 4.0 but according to [here](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/02/21/powershell-windows-restore.aspx):

> The other critical point to know when using Checkpoint-Computer cmdlet
>   is that you can only create a restore point with this cmdlet once
>   every 24 hours. You can run the command again, but it will only keep
>   the last restore point

[image]
So is there a way that I can make hourly restore point in powershell?

What is "MODIFY_SETTING" for restore point type?
What difference it will make for "restoring a file" if i use different "restorepointtype" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is. You already have the code to create a restore point. To do it once per hour, use task scheduler to run each hour.

As for `MODIFY_SETTINGS`:

> MODIFY_SETTINGS
>
> 12   An application has had features added or removed.

Source: [CreateRestorePoint @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378847(v=vs.85).aspx)

Sample converted to PowerShell (I've set the type to `MODIFY_SETTINGS`):

```
$strDesc = "Automatic Restore Point"
$systemrestore = [wmiclass]'\\.\root\default:SystemRestore'
$systemrestore.CreateRestorePoint($strDesc, 12, 100)
```

Comment: My question is I want to do it in powershell , it wont create 2nd system restore point within 24 hours....but vbs will do...

Comment: Then convert it. It's 90% done already.. See updated answer. :)

Comment: well, this way works...I wanted to use  `Checkpoint-Computer` cmdlet

Comment: But when Microsoft says "Beginning in Windows 8, Checkpoint-Computer cannot create more than one checkpoint each day." (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849822.aspx) , then it actually means that it won't allow it, so you have to use another solution. We're not going to rewrite the `Checkpint-Computer` cmdlet for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd just enable shadowcopies for that data instead. No need for a system checkpoint (at this point, without me knowing more info).